# Clarification on "How do I propose or vote on tag synonyms?"

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, privileges-page

On https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms, we got:

> Users with this privilege and a total answer score of 5 or more on the tag, can **suggest** tag synonyms. Users with a total answer score (total upvotes minus total downvotes) of 5 or more on the tag, can **vote** for tag synonyms.

Looks like that could be shortened to:

> Users with this privilege and a total answer score of 5 or more (total upvotes minus total downvotes) on the tag can **suggest** (or **vote** for) tag synonyms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not quite. You need the actual **create tag synonyms** privilege *in addition to* a score of 5 or more on the tag in order to suggest a tag synonym. You **don't** need that privilege in order to vote on them, though. You only need a score of 5 or more on the tag in order to do that.

They should remain separated to emphasize that users who don't yet have that privilege are still able to vote on the synonyms. Otherwise people reading that privileges wiki might assume that the privilege is required for both of them.

Comment: That distinction is easy to miss. Perhaps something like *but without this privilege* should be added to the second sentence.